# HttpContent.ReadFromJsonAsync Won't Deserialize Generic Object (Blazor WebAssembly)

Tags: c#, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

Here is a scenario involving two classes:

```csharp
public class ServiceResult<T> where T : class
{
    public bool Succeeded { get; private set; }

    public string Message { get; private set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> Errors { get; private set; }

    public T Payload { get; private set; }

    public static ServiceResult<T> Success(T payload, string message)
    {
        return new ServiceResult<T>
        {
            Payload = payload,
            Succeeded = true,
            Message = message
        };
    }

    public static ServiceResult<T> Failure(IEnumerable<string> errors, string message)
    {
        return new ServiceResult<T>
        {
            Errors = errors,
            Message = messgae,
            Succeeded = false
        };
    }

}
```

and

```csharp
public class UserDto
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public virtual List<GDPClaim> Claims { get; set; }
}
```

when making this call:

```csharp
HttpResponseMessage response = await Http.PostAsJsonAsync("api/user", model);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
     ServiceResult<UserDto> result = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<ServiceResult<UserDto>>();
}
```

I get this error:

Error:

```
blazor.webassembly.js:1 crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at GDPHomes.Admin.Pages.Users.ValidFormSubmit() in C:\Users\mikejr76\Desktop\Development\Web\_Production\GDPHomes\GDPHomes\Admin\Pages\Users.razor:line 121
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.EditForm.HandleSubmitAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle)
```

This is the response from the server:
[image]
[image]

But when I change the call to this it works fine:

```csharp
HttpResponseMessage response = await Http.PostAsJsonAsync("api/user", model);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
   UserDto user = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<UserDto>();
}
```

**Also in the API I change from returning the ServiceResult to just returning the UserDto.
I couldn't find anywhere in the docs that said you cannot deserialize a generic object. I had even seen a tutorial in which I saw a generic object deserialized using ReadFromJsonAsync.

I appreciate any help on this!

Comment: I think it is related to the deserialization of private fields.

The HttpClient Extensions methods like ```PostAsJsonAsync``` using the System.Text.Json Serializer. My guess is, that your ```ServiceResult<T>``` is not easy to handle, because of the private setter. There is no constructor that takes all arguments either, so the serializer doesn't know how to create an instance and set the values correctly. I'm not sure why you get a ```NullReferenceException``` but I would try to create the ```ServiceResult<T>``` also as plain DTO first to check if this solves your issue and work from there.

Comment: Wow, that is a very insightful response. I am going to try it and I will report back on my findings. Thank you.

Comment: Just a straight DTO did work. I ended up creating a Map function on the ServiceResult that maps the fields to the ServiceResultDto I made. I call that in the controller like: return Ok(result.Map());

Comment: @Michael W Riemer Jr I facing same issue, return null when calling `content.ReadFromJsonAsync<ApiResult<User>>();` , can you post the code how you solved it? Thanks

Comment: @HowardHee the first comment suggests using public setters instead of private. The third comment says that worked. The deserializer can't set those private fields. Are you sure you're having the same issue? Things have changed since 2020 too, with the introduction of records and `init` as an alternative to `private set`