# ReadAsAsync cast custom class return null for .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, httpcontent

I have a old MVC program, converting to .net core. but I am facing ReadAsAsync() casting issue. Same code worked on old MVC, but not .NET Core.

I have a User model:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public int Status { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

I try test the result by use the following code to get the wep api HttpResponseMessage:

```
string responseContent = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

And successful return following User data:

```
{"id":1, "username":"howard","password":"xxxxx","status":1,"Address":null}
```

When I cast the response to User model use code below, is working find and return User model.

```
//worked
var data = await message.Content?.ReadAsAsync<User>();
```

[image]

But when I added a custom ApiResult class, it's become not working, and return null for "result" property in ApiResult class.

```
//not work
var data = await message.Content?.ReadAsAsync<ApiResult<User>>()
```

[image]

But it's worked on old MVC:

[image]

My ApiResult class:

```
public class ApiResult
{
    public bool CustomizedisSuccess { get; set; }

    public string CustomizedErrorMsg { get; set; }

    public static ApiResult<T> Success<T>(T result = default(T))
    {
        return new ApiResult<T>
        {
            Result = result,
            CustomizedisSuccess = true,
            CustomizedErrorMsg = "Error"
        };
    }
}

public class ApiResult<T> : ApiResult
{
    public T Result { get; set; }
}
```

The result always return null, by right suppose cast to User model. Same code worked in previous MVC but not .NET Core.

**Update:**

I am tried use ReadFromJsonAsync, but it's not working, also return null.

```
// not work also
var result = await message.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<ApiResult<User>>();
```

same case with me:

[HttpContent.ReadFromJsonAsync Won't Deserialize Generic Object (Blazor WebAssembly)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65317413/httpcontent-readfromjsonasync-wont-deserialize-generic-object-blazor-webassemb)

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/21030

Comment: The JSON you are receiving from the API is for class `User` only. It can not be deserialized to the class which does not have the similar structure. So you can's deserialize it to ApiResult object.

Comment: but I passed the `User` class into `ApiResult<T>` as generic type

Comment: Your `ApiResult<T>` class has `T Result` property. Where do you see `"Result"` property in your json? You can't just randomly deserialize jsons into random classes. Properties have to match. It would work for `{"result": {...}}` json but not for the one you've showed us.

Comment: @HowardHee [HttpContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent?view=net-6.0) doesn't have a `ReadAsAsync` method, it has a [ReadFromJsonAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent?view=net-6.0#extension-methods) extension method. Where did `ReadAsAsync` come from? Is that a custom extension method? Shouldn't you use the built-in method instead?

Comment: @HowardHee [ReadAsAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh835763(v=vs.118)) is deprecated since 2015 even in ASP.NET. I don't think it ever made it to ASP.NET Core. Instead of trying to use 7 year old classes and patterns, create a new ASP.NET Core MVC or WebAPI project to see how things work *now*. There's no need for that `ApiResult` for example, result classes inheriting from `IActionResult` are already available. `return Ok(myObject)` will return a 200 response with the payload serialized as JSON

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos I am using System.Net.Http.Formatting

Comment: Which the docs show is deprecated since 2015. You shouldn't be using it in the first place, unless the MVC project predates 2015. The built-in method is called `ReadFromJsonAsync`. If you use that deprecated method, you probably use other deprecated classes as well

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos Really thanks for the suggestion, I will try change it by using `ReadFromJsonAsync`

Comment: For example, there's usually no reason to deal with HttpRequestMessage directly in Web API, that's what binding is for. In scenarios that require greater control it may be better to use endpoints or even minimal APIs directly.

Comment: Actually in my ApiResult class have added some customize property, get the response with some customized property data, that's why need to do that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246816/discussion-between-howard-hee-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Answer (score 1):

Deserialize it as a `User` (because that is what the JSON is) and embed it in an `ApiResult` afterward. Looks like you already have a helper method for it.

```
var user = await content?.ReadAsAsync<User>();
var data = ApiResult.Success(user);
```

Comment: HttpContent doesn't have a ReadAsAsync method. That was [an extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh835763(v=vs.118)) that's deprecated since 2015 in .NET Framework. I don't think it ever made it to .NET Core. .NET 6 has a `ReadFromJsonAsync` though

Comment: Hi @John Wu, if follow your code, the result will always `true`, then I am unable check the 'if(result == null)' conditions.

Comment: @HowardHee I don't understand. The only variable in your example that is named `result` is of type `T` which is a `User`, so it will never be `true`, because it is not a Boolean. Can you explain?

Comment: @John Wu, I found the root cause, it's because the api return from old MVC post action included ApiResult<ApiUserData>,  have a message handler (`DelegatingHandler`) to modified the return api response to success and wrapped by ApiResult<>. That's why I get null when `ReadFromJsonAsync<ApiResult<User>>` but fine in `ReadFromJsonAsync<User>`. Once I modified the api return data by included ApiResult<>, it;s working fine now.